# Paypal HTML buttons for Installment Plan gives error when payment cycles are more then 4

Tags: paypal, paypal-buttons

I have created a HTML button for installment plan. Everything works good until the payment cycles increases to 4 or greater then 4. It throws the following error:

**Only four payment cycles are allowed in installment plan**

Also there were no variables where the max payment cycles is set in my HTML button code. What am I missing ?

Answer (score 1):

The PayPal Installment Plans only have up to 4 cycles, you can't go beyond this variable - [PayPal Installment Plan Information](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/installment_step_1/#enter-installment-plan-information)